# How to install puppet 3.X client on Debian 9 stretch?

Tags: installation, puppet

**I put in the repos of older Debian / Ubuntu distros:**

```
root@canais-c-solr01:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppet.list 
# Puppetlabs products
deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty main
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty main

# Puppetlabs dependencies
deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty dependencies
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty dependencies

# Puppetlabs devel (uncomment to activate)
# deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty devel
# deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com trusty devel
```

**And as I try installing a version I got from apt-cache show puppet:**

```
root@canais-c-solr01:~# apt-get install puppet=3.8.7-1puppetlabs1 puppet-common=3.8.7-1puppetlabs1  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 puppet-common : Depends: libaugeas-ruby but it is not installable or
                          libaugeas-ruby1.9.1 but it is not installable or
                          libaugeas-ruby1.8 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Updating the master to a more recent puppet is not an option for now.**

Comment: You need to either use a Puppet AIO, which did not exist back then, or install via `gem`, which would be supported by Ruby 2.1 at the latest for that version of Puppet. Stretch does not have a package for that either as it is too old. Your options are basically starting to look like rvm, Docker, etc. Otherwise, you have to downgrade to Debian 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get install sysv-rc libruby

dpkg -i /tmp/libaugeas-ruby_0.5.0-2_all.deb
dpkg -i /tmp/puppet-common_3.8.4-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
dpkg -i /tmp/puppet_3.8.4-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
```

We had to get those packages from another debian machine.

You will get an error after trying to install the .deb for the first time. After that you will have to do.

```
apt-get install -f 
apt-get purge puppet puppet-common
```

and then try again.